# hitTest check of a movie clip without checking its parent

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

What I am trying to do is check for collision of a movie clip instance named enemy with an instance of a movie clip called laser (which is inside a movie clip called ship).

When enemy collides with ship I want the main timeline to go to frame 2.

When enemy collides with laser I want the main timeline to go to frame 3.

The problem is that when ship.laser collides with enemy, it also counts as if ship was colliding with enemy.

Is there a way to check for the collision of ship.laser and enemy without checking for ship and enemy at the same time?

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, collide);
function collide(event:Event)
{
    if (enemy.hitTestObject(ship) )
    {
        gotoAndStop(2);
        trace("hit Ship");

    }

    if (enemy.hitTestObject(ship.laser))
    {
        trace("hit laser");
        gotoAndStop(3);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal that if the enemy collides with laser it also collides with ship, because laser is part of the ship.

What you can do is just to check if enemy collided with laser:

```
if (enemy.hitTestObject(ship) )
{
    if (enemy.hitTestObject(ship.laser))
    {
        // collides with ship AND laser
    } else {
        // collides with ship only, but not with the laser
    }
}
```

Comment: The collision with the laser is working properly now but I am getting this errror when the ship collides with the enemy

TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
 at flash.display::DisplayObject/_hitTest()
 at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
 at MethodInfo-9()

Comment: Well it seems like one of the properties you provide is null - either enemy, ship, or ship.laser. Put some efforts, I cannot help you with a magic stick!

Comment: I think I figured out why it is giving me a null error. The laser movie clip only  appears for a few seconds when the laser is being fired but then it disappears after the firing animation is over. How can I check for its collision only when it is on the stage? so that there wont be a hitTest while it is not in the stage

Comment: Just add check if laser exists: `if (ship.laser && enemy.hitTestObject(ship.laser))`... Do some research first :)